# Intersection of planes

Tags: vector-spaces, plane-curves

A line perpendicular to the plane $ 3x-5y+4z-11=0 $ passes through the origin. At what point does this normal intersects the plane?

Answer (score 0):

The equations of the line are

$$x=3t$$
$$y=-5t$$
$$z=4t$$ thus for the intersection we have

$$9t+25t+16t=11$$

so $$x=\frac{3}{25}$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{5}$$
$$z=\frac{4}{25}$$

Comment: why did you square the (3,-5,4)?
you got this 9t+25t+16t=11?

Comment: I just substituted the equations, the the square happens, automatically.

Comment: got it, thanks.